# Relations between finite Hecke algebras and affine Hecke algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, hecke-algebras

A finite Hecke algebra $H_n(q)$ of type $A$ is an associated algebra generated by $T_1, \ldots, T_{n-1}$ with relations
\begin{align}
& T_i T_j = T_j T_i, |i-j|>1, \\
& T_i T_{i+1} T_i = T_{i+1} T_i T_{i+1}, \\
& (T_i-q)(T_i+1) = 0.
\end{align}

An affine Hecke algebra $\widehat{H_n}(q)$ of type $A$ is an associated algebra generated by $T_1, \ldots, T_{n-1}, X_1^{\pm 1}, \ldots, X_n^{\pm 1}$ with relations
\begin{align}
& T_i T_j = T_j T_i, |i-j|>1, \\
& T_i T_{i+1} T_i = T_{i+1} T_i T_{i+1}, \\
& (T_i-q)(T_i+1) = 0, \\
& X_i^{\pm 1} X_k^{\pm 1} = X_k^{\pm 1} X_i^{\pm 1}, 1 \leq i, k \leq n, \\
& X_k X_k^{-1} = X_k^{-1} X_k =1, \\
& T_i X_k = X_k T_i, |i-k|>1, \\
& X_{i+1} = q^{-1} T_i X_i T_i, 1 \leq i < n.
\end{align}
Is $H_n(q)$ a subalgebra of $\widehat{H_n}(q)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: what happens if you send $X_i$ to  $0$ ?